# Adding ellipsis to divs inside table columns

Tags: css

In my code I'm trying to make the content of the `file-wrapper` div ellipsify so that the width of the table stretches 100% to screen width.

I simply cannot figure out where I'm going wrong, as the `file-wrapper` div has a specified pixel width.

EDIT: I've simplified the code down to the basics now.

```css
table {
 width: 100%; 
}

.file-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="file-wrapper">
        testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like it's doing what you're describing. What is the problem?

Comment: The other TDs are not holding their widths. If you resize your browser the content doesn't keep ellipsifying. The table should be 100% viewable no matter your browser width.

Comment: width: calc(100% - 214px) in your case does not make sense, because it tells "make the div 100% - 214px the size of the cell", bust the cell itself by default spans in order to fit all of its contents, and the ellipsis will never be shown. In you case you would need fix the width of the td to make it work.

Comment: Yes are you are right about that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely certain, but I suspect this has something to do with a clash between the `100%` width of the table and the `border` attribute in

```
<table border="1">
```

See this modification using a width of `98vw` instead of `100%`:

```css
table {
width: 98vw; 
}

.file-wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: calc(98vw - 214px);
}

.spacer {
width: 10px;
}

.icon {
width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="icon"></td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
            <td class="file">Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="icon"></td>
            <td class="spacer"></td>
            <td class="file">
                <div class="file-wrapper">
                    testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The border is just to see the width of the empty cells. As @Eduard Malakhov mentioned above, I've got the fixed width of the div wrong because it's looking at 100% of its parent TD, not the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below simple css

```
.file-wrapper{
    width: 60px;/* Change as per requirement*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not specifying a fixed width. The div's width depends on the width of the browser.

Comment: Make width auto and set max width.